# How to find counter example to show that a vector field is not conservative?

Tags: vector-analysis

[image]

I know that to show it is not a conservation vector field I could find a closed parameterized path and then calculate the line integral such that it is not equal to zero, I've tried using a unit circle but I couldn't do this integration, what other paths could I try?

Comment: It's defined everywhere, so its differential can't be zero. I.e., it's curl should be nonzero. In order to be not conservative that is.

Answer (score 1):

An easier way to do it is to just show that $\nabla \times F \neq 0$. This implies that $F$ is not conservative

Comment: Could you explain why that is?

Comment: By Stokes theorem, $\iint \nabla \times F \cdot \hat n da = \oint F\cdot dl$. So, as conservative fields have RHS $=0$ for all possible paths, the LHS $= 0$ too for all possible paths. This implies that the integrand itself is $0$ i.e. $\nabla \times F \cdot  = 0$

Comment: Is that the gradient of F? Is there a way to do it without Stokes theorem because I haven't learnt that yet.

Comment: What is? $\nabla \times F$? If this is what you are asking, then no. It is the curl of $F$.